# Bootstrap 4 How to change image height without width in column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have code like below

```
<div class="col-sm-8" id="slider">
 <img src="{{asset('images/pustynia.jpg')}}" id="slider_obrazek" class="img-fluid" />
</div>
```

Orginal size of image is very large, so I would like to change only its height without width. I've tried to change css img height but it is not working. Only width is working. While I'am changing width, height is resized too. I am using percent as values.  It's not good solution because image must have the same width as parent container.  How should I solve this problem? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: please add some code ;-)

Comment: so you want to crop your image on resize?

Comment: You can use img-responsive

Comment: Not crop but shrink

Comment: img-responsive is not helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should set different **CSS** properties for both **`div`** and **`img`** elements

Try something like this:

```
#slider {
width: 800px; /* your desired WIDTH goes here */
height: 600px; /* your desired HEIGHT goes here */
}

#slider_obrazek {
width: 100%;
height: 100%; /* or auto */
}
```

You might get some results with this.
Tell me if it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

## slider_o_brazek{

width: 100%;
height: 50% for example
}

## slider{

```
height: 100%
```

}